# flutter : How to Expand only one Card at a time in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I have a coupon cards, In this cards i want to open (expand) only one at a time.

This is my Code coupon_page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../Utils/GlobalColor/global_color.dart';
import '../Utils/GlobalWidgetPages/app_bar_center_text.dart';
import 'Components/coupon_card.dart';


class CouponPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CouponPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CouponPage> createState() => _CouponPageState();
}

class _CouponPageState extends State<CouponPage> {
  List input = [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "OfferTitle": "50% off on 2nd Pizza",
    },
    {
      "Id": 3,
      "OfferTitle": "FREE CHOCOLAVA CAKE",
    },
    {
      "Id": 6,
      "OfferTitle": "60% OFF",
    },
    {
      "Id": 7,
      "OfferTitle": "STEP DOWN BOGO",
    },
    {
      "Id": 8,
      "OfferTitle": "FREE GARLIC BREAD STICKS",
    },
    {
      "Id": 9,
      "OfferTitle": "FLAT 25% OFF",
    }
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBarWithCenterText(
          text: "Coupon & Offers",
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        backgroundColor: MyColor.bgLightColor,
        body: ListView.builder(
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 21.0, bottom: 20),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: input.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: index == 0 ? 0 : 12,
                ),
                child: CouponCard(data: input[index]),
              );
            }));
  }
}
```

this is my coupon)card.dart page

```
import 'package:dotted_border/dotted_border.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../Utils/GlobalColor/global_color.dart';
import '../../Utils/GlobalTextStyles/global_text_styles.dart';

class CouponCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final data;

  const CouponCard({Key? key, this.data}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CouponCard> createState() => _CouponCardState();
}

class _CouponCardState extends State<CouponCard> {
  bool isViewDetailsOpen = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 16, 0, 0),
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: MyColor.whiteColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: MyColor.greyColor.withOpacity(0.2),
              blurRadius: 7.0,
              spreadRadius: 3,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16, bottom: 12),
              child: Text(
                "${widget.data["Id"]}",
                style: textStyleWith14500(MyColor.blackColor),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16, bottom: 14),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        isViewDetailsOpen = !isViewDetailsOpen;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "View Details",
                          style: textStyleWith12400(MyColor.darkGreyColor),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 6,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          !isViewDetailsOpen
                              ? Icons.arrow_drop_down
                              : Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                          color: MyColor.darkGreyColor,
                          size: 20,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            isViewDetailsOpen
                ? Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 7.0, bottom: 14),
                        child: DottedBorder(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          color: MyColor.greyColor,
                          dashPattern: [9, 9],
                          child: Container(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 16.0,
                          right: 16,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          "Code ",
                          style: textStyleWith12600(MyColor.blackColor),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 16.0,
                          right: 16,
                          top: 5,
                          bottom: 5,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          "${widget.data["OfferTitle"]}",
                          style: textStyleWith12600(MyColor.blackColor),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                : Container(),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Container(
                height: 40,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: MyColor.greyColor2,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(8),
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8))),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "TAP TO APPLY",
                    style: textStyleWith12500(MyColor.darkGreyColor),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

How will be expand only one card at a time.

Comment: I just ran your exact code and only one card is expanding at a time, what exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to make it open only one at the time :

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../Utils/GlobalColor/global_color.dart';
import '../Utils/GlobalWidgetPages/app_bar_center_text.dart';
import 'Components/coupon_card.dart';


class CouponPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CouponPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CouponPage> createState() => _CouponPageState();
}

class _CouponPageState extends State<CouponPage> {
  List input = [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "OfferTitle": "50% off on 2nd Pizza",
    },
    {
      "Id": 3,
      "OfferTitle": "FREE CHOCOLAVA CAKE",
    },
    {
      "Id": 6,
      "OfferTitle": "60% OFF",
    },
    {
      "Id": 7,
      "OfferTitle": "STEP DOWN BOGO",
    },
    {
      "Id": 8,
      "OfferTitle": "FREE GARLIC BREAD STICKS",
    },
    {
      "Id": 9,
      "OfferTitle": "FLAT 25% OFF",
    }
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBarWithCenterText(
          text: "Coupon & Offers",
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        backgroundColor: MyColor.bgLightColor,
        body: ListView.builder(
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 21.0, bottom: 20),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: input.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
              bool isOpen = false;
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: index == 0 ? 0 : 12,
                ),
                child: CouponCard(data: input[index] , onTap: (){ 
                  setState(() {
                        isOpen = !isOpen;
                      });} , isOpen : isOpen),
              );
            }));
  }
}
```

coupon_cart.dart :

```
import 'package:dotted_border/dotted_border.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../Utils/GlobalColor/global_color.dart';
import '../../Utils/GlobalTextStyles/global_text_styles.dart';

class CouponCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final data;
  final bool isOpen;
  final Function()? onTap;

  const CouponCard({Key? key, this.data, required this.isOpen, this.onTap}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CouponCard> createState() => _CouponCardState();
}

class _CouponCardState extends State<CouponCard> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 16, 0, 0),
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: MyColor.whiteColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: MyColor.greyColor.withOpacity(0.2),
              blurRadius: 7.0,
              spreadRadius: 3,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16, bottom: 12),
              child: Text(
                "${widget.data["Id"]}",
                style: textStyleWith14500(MyColor.blackColor),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16, bottom: 14),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: widget.onTap,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "View Details",
                          style: textStyleWith12400(MyColor.darkGreyColor),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 6,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          !widget.isOpen
                              ? Icons.arrow_drop_down
                              : Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                          color: MyColor.darkGreyColor,
                          size: 20,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            widget.isOpen
                ? Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 7.0, bottom: 14),
                        child: DottedBorder(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          color: MyColor.greyColor,
                          dashPattern: [9, 9],
                          child: Container(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 16.0,
                          right: 16,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          "Code ",
                          style: textStyleWith12600(MyColor.blackColor),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 16.0,
                          right: 16,
                          top: 5,
                          bottom: 5,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          "${widget.data["OfferTitle"]}",
                          style: textStyleWith12600(MyColor.blackColor),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                : Container(),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Container(
                height: 40,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: MyColor.greyColor2,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(8),
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8))),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "TAP TO APPLY",
                    style: textStyleWith12500(MyColor.darkGreyColor),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

if you face any issue with `Function()?` please let me know

Comment: no it not working

Comment: I fixed the issue , you can recopy  coupon_cart.dart and try again , and let me know if there is an issue .